# How to use jquery.dirtyforms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

I am getting confused on how to use [jquery.dirtyforms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms).

I am trying to create a simple form with a text box and submit button. If the user modify the text box and try to refresh the page or click on a link inside the page before saving the result, Dirty Forms plugin should alert the user. But nothing is working.

Below is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').dirtyForms({ 
        dialog: { title: 'Wait!' }, 
        message: 'You forgot to save your details. If you leave now, they will be lost forever.' 
    });
    });

</script>
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input id="input" type="text" />
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with this code and how to use this plugin?

Comment: It does work, but the message and title attribute don't work. Also if you run it on your pc in a html file, the link `//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js` doesnt work. it will also try and load it from your pc instead of http/https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work if you remove the title and message from the dirtyforms call. As per the documentation:

```
// Customize the title and message.
// Note that title is not supported by browser dialogs, so you should 
// only set it if you are using a custom dialog or dialog module.
$('form').dirtyForms({ 
    dialog: { title: 'Wait!' }, 
    message: 'You forgot to save your details. If you leave now, they will be lost forever.' 
});
```

Because you are trying to use the default browser dialog, these extra attributes cause the dirtyform code to break.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').dirtyForms();
    });

</script>
<form action="/" method="post">
        <input id="input" type="text" />
        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>

<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tank you that work with me but i do i simple modification with the dirtyform src link i added http:// before cdn

Answer (score 2):

While @Joffutt came up with a working solution, there is an explanation for this behavior that he overlooked. The issue is that you are setting a dialog module here:

```
dialog: { title: 'Wait!' },
```

This tells Dirty Forms *not use* the default browser dialog and to use your custom dialog module. However, you did not complete the rest of the custom dialog module registration [as per the documentation](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#custom-dialog-integration) (namely, you don't have an open method defined), so you have an invalid configuration.

If you don't want a custom dialog module, you should not define a `dialog:` in your configuration.